# jQuery - Display text above rotating image

Tags: jquery, html

HTML code:

```
<div id="img-wrapper">
  <img src="images/1.png" title="Picture 1" class="my-img" />
  <img src="images/2.png" title="Picture 2" class="my-img" />
  <img src="images/3.png" title="Picture 3" class="my-img" />           
</div>
```

Styles:

```
#img-wrapper {
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
}
.my-img {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

I use jquery to rotate images(it works fine). But I wish to display a text above this image. I did tried including a DIV at the bottom of img-wrapper. But that text is displayed behind the images. I use fadeIn() and fadeOut() to display the images, when rotated.

How to place a div above the images ?

**EDIT**

I had made some changes to the code. I am now using Cycle plugin to display images based on this question's answer: [jQuery - Image rotation gets faster when focused after the focus was on another Chrome Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366980/jquery-image-rotation-gets-faster-when-focused-after-the-focus-was-on-another)

Now, my previous solution for displaying text is not working ! :(

**EDIT**

Solution for the above issue: use a higher z-index value.

Comment: You can use a coin slider plugin in jquery check it http://workshop.rs/2010/04/coin-slider-image-slider-with-unique-effects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `z-index` of the div you want to place above the images:

```
.div-above-images {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/Adding_z-index

```
Warning! z-index only has an effect if an element is positioned.
```

Comment: Yes. That did the trick. :)
I have tried that z-index before(before posting this question). But didn't bothered using absolute position. Thank you

Comment: @VppMan Np. The MDN links above says that z-index only takes effect if the element is positioned.

Comment: Thank you. Most of the time I used to do trial & error method when it comes to CSS.

Comment: I think, I got it. I used a higher value for z-index

Answer (score 0):

You could create the div before #img-wrapper. Any reason for not doing that?

Comment: But that text will be hided, when picture fades in !

Comment: Are you saying the picture will cover the text when the picture fades in? It shouldn't; say you have a <div id="caption">Text</div> above <div id="img-wrapper">...</div>. #img-wrapper shouldn't cover #caption. For each change in #img-wrapper, you can also update the innerHTML of #caption.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with jQuery is:

```
$('#img-wrapper').before('<div>text</div>');
```

Comment: But they will be hided when the picture fades in !! I have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

you need this

```
$('#img-wrapper img:first').before('<div>text</div>');
```